# Vue bootstrap select multiple prop not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, select, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I tried to implement the form select vue bootstrap component but it does not seem to work. On their page (https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-select) in the section multiple select support it is suggested to use the prop to enable multiple selections. However, in my application as well as in the snippet on the mentioned website, I can only select multiple items while holding control or keeping the mouse button clicked. That is very unintuitive and I want to implement a select where numerous items can be selected by just clicking once without holding additional buttons. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: This is normal behaviour of the select form field, that is used by the bootstrap-vue component. Why don't you use check boxes instead?

Comment: I want the items in a dropdown menu and I the website didn't habe a good example on how to achieve this unfortunately. There is just one example with one checkbox but I want a listing of the items similar to the one in select.

Comment: As far as I know, is this not possible with the b-form-select component. The only way is to make your own component that has that behaviour. Without utilizing the <select multiple> html object. But using div's with the right css class.

Comment: OK, thank you for your help!